# How do I retrieve data from an xhr request?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Here is my situation:

I have a JS function that creates an XMLHttpRequest object. The request is opened, and I'm calling the "GET" method on a specified url. The request works, as in it gets to the url destination and executes the code in the destination, but I'm not sure how to access a variable in the destination code.

Here's what I've got:

JS:

```
function fillTestsTable()
{
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }   

    xhr.open("GET", "./db-queries/get-tests.php");
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

PHP destination file:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306"   ,   "exampre2_tplugin"   ,   ",Vyml.F!@(}{"   ,   "exampre2_totaltoefltimeplugin");

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TOEFLTESTS";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //return $result;
    ?>
```

What I am trying to do is return the data in the $result variable in the php. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: do you mean return data from your `fillTestsTable` javascript function?

Comment: @RamRaider No, I mean return the data form the code executed in the ./db-queries/get-tests.php file.

Comment: Quentin suggested using `echo` or `print` - you can also use `exit()` or `die()` from within your PHP code. The format that is `echo`ed depends what you want to do with it - it can be plain text, html, xml, json or other... use a loop to iterate through the recordset and echo/print the data

Comment: @RamRaider Ok. Follow up question: is there an xhr field or method that would store this data? For example, is there an xhr.response or xhr.getResponse() that would give me back this data that I'm echoing? I looked through the mozilla apis and I couldn't find an exact fit.

Comment: My goal is to get the contents of the $result variable in the php so I can use in the javascript..Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: How are you hoping to use the response data in javascript? You cannot pass the actual PHP object back and forth but you can output the recordset in a wide variety of formats, it depends what you are needing / wanting to do with it

Comment: So the php object contains the contents of a mysql table. I want to take this data and display it in HTML. The reason I have the JavaScript as the middleman is because ideally the script will be called after a certain event fires.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `return` is used to return a value from the current function to where that function was called.

To output data in the HTTP response use `echo` or `print`.

Note that `mysqli_query` returns a mysqli_result object so you will need to extact the data you want from that (e.g. with [`fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)) and then convert it to a suitable text format (e.g. with [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Answer (score 0):

For example: if you wanted to return JSON formatted data for your Ajax callback function to play with you might do something like this:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306"   ,   "exampre2_tplugin"   ,   ",Vyml.F!@(}{"   ,   "exampre2_totaltoefltimeplugin");

    $data=[];   //store recordset here

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TOEFLTESTS";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if( $result ){ /* iterate through the recordset, add each row to output data */
        while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
            $data[]=$rs;
        }
    }
    /* send data back to the ajax callback function */
    exit( json_encode( $data ) );
?>
```

There are many ways you could proceed with this but it helps to clearly define the purpose and identify how your app is to work. The `callback` will then manipulate the response data to add new rows to your HTML table. Knowing what the callback is to do will generally ( or can ) affect the format of data you return - in your case if it is simply to be new rows in an HTML table it would be better to format the data server-side as HTML and send back raw html text.

---

Using Ajax allows your app to request data of whatever sort without the need to reload the page ( usually a traditional form submission )

As a basic example of populating an HTML table following a basic ajax request ( POST rather than GET but would work the same )

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'maps';
        $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        ob_clean();

        $sql='select `name`,`address`,`lat`,`lng` from `maps` limit 10';
        $res=$db->query( $sql );

        while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
            printf('
                <tr>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                </tr>',
                $rs->name,
                $rs->address,
                $rs->lat,
                $rs->lng
            );
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Ajax: fetch data from db - add to table</title>
        <script>
            const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( params );
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' value='Fetch Data' />
        <table></table>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').onclick=function(e){
            ajax( location.href, false, function(r){
                this.innerHTML=r
            }.bind( e.target.nextElementSibling ))
        }
    </script>
</html>
```